# selection sort list of string arrays

Tags: arrays, string, list, sorting

So if I have a list of string arrays and then use user input to add arrays containing three elements to the list.
How to use selection sort to sort the arrays alphabetically?

I understood how to use selection sort to sort integers. 
I figured out how to use it for a string array.
But trying to use it with a list of string arrays is making me go crazy.

When I did this:

```
int pos_min,temp;

for (int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    pos_min = i; 

    for (int j=i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
    {

        if (list[j].CompareTo(list[pos_min]) < 0)
        {

            pos_min = j;
        }                                          
    }


    if (pos_min != i)
    {
        temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[pos_min];
        list[pos_min] = temp;
    }
}
```

I got

> string[] does not contain a definition for CompareTo...

in the if statement.
When I added an `[i]` before the `[j]` in the if statement I got

> Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to int

in temp =.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent letter as number. Something like this

```
int aLetterNumber = 'a';
int zLetterNumber = 'z';
```

Let's represent 'A' as 1, 'B' as 2, 'C' as 3 etc... 
For example we will get CAB word to sort

1. change every letter to number, you will get that array 3,1,2
2. sort that array.that will be 1,2,3
3. change your number to letter and you will get A,B,C.

Comment: I am sorry but I could not figure out how to implement that. Not in a way that works anyway.